# I need creating a program en QT for view cameras SAPERA++

Tags: c++, qt, file, sapera

i have this program that i copy the other post: [Sapera++ API with Qt undefined reference to '_imp__ZN11SapLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177084/sapera-api-with-qt-undefined-reference-to-imp-zn11saplocation)
My Program is:

**SapCamara1.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2021-07-06T09:36:29
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = SapCamara1
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

#CONFIG += c++11 #puede comentarse

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapAcqDevice.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapAcqToBufThruCab.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapAcquisition.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapBayer.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapBuffer.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapBufferRemote.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapBufferRoi.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapBufferWithTrash.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapBufferWithTrashAndRoi.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapCab.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapClassBasic.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapClassBasicDef.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapClassBasicObsolete.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapClassBasicRes.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapColorConversion.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapCounter.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapData.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapDisplay.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapDynamicLut.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapFeature.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapFlatField.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapGio.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapGraphic.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapLut.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapManager.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapMetadata.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapMultiAcqToBufThruCab.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapPerformance.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapPixPro.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapProcessing.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapRTPro.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapRTProDesign.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapRTProDesignOnBrdBuffers.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapTransfer.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapTransferEx.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapView.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapXferMultiNode.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/SapXferNode.h \
#        ../../../../../../../Program Files/Teledyne DALSA/Sapera/Classes/Basic/corenv.h \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += 'C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Classes\Basic'
INCLUDEPATH += 'C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Include'
INCLUDEPATH += 'C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Lib'

LIBS += 'C:\Program Files\Teledyne DALSA\Sapera\Lib\Win64\SapClassBasic.lib'



# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

And
I am not sure if I am placing correctly the index and resourcefile of the arguments requested by SapAcquisition.
**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "SapClassBasic.h"
#include "SapAcquisition.h"

HWND disp;
//bool success;


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //disp=(HWND)ui->graphicsView->winId();
    disp=(HWND)ui->graphicsView->winId();
    SapAcquisition *pAcq=new SapAcquisition(SapLocation("Nano-M1450_1",1),"T_Nano-M1450_IAB_1.ccf");
    //Nano-M1450
    //T_Nano-M1450_IAB_1.ccf

    SapBuffer *pBuffer=new SapBuffer(1,pAcq);
    //SapView *pView=new SapView(pBuffer,disp);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

But i can't see the image of the camera:

```
09:35:29: Starting C:\Users\MSA\Desktop\Adrian Pilataxi\tutorial open cv camara\SapCamara1\build-SapCamara1-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\debug\SapCamara1.exe ...
=>LOG :  : Loading logger parameter file 'C:\Program Files\GenICam_v2_4\log\config\DebugLogging.properties'
09:35:33: C:/Users/MSA/Desktop/Adrian Pilataxi/tutorial open cv camara/SapCamara1/build-SapCamara1-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug/debug/SapCamara1.exe exited with code 0
```

The cameras I am using are: Nano-M1450 of the GenieNano series from Teledyne DALSA, I don't know if anyone can help me with any suggestions to be able to observe the image obtained from the camera through the GUI.

Comment: The Problem looks like no lib path inclusion for SapLocation.The error itself says undefined reference to SapLocation just include the correct library path.Just confirm weather included lib contains the SapLocation class or not.

Comment: Why have you commented out the `SapView` line? Without this line, it seems to me you only hold the image in memory and or not displaying it in any way. (Note that I'm __not__ familiar with sapera).

Comment: I need create a simple program for i see the cameras, but i can't